# why 'np.random.uniform' in python is same in population size?

Tags: python, numpy, random, population

I wanna define a structure with python3.x. this structure is the initial population, but I don't know, why in this loop, random numbers are the same?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.shape_base import _dstack_dispatcher
from numpy.random import default_rng

Xmin=-30;Xmax=30;n=2;MaxIter=200;nP=50 
Fc=0.7
nC=2*round(Fc*nP/2)#;print(nC)
Fm=0.1
nM=round(Fm*nP)#;print(nM)
Pi_M=0.02

empty_ind={'X':[],'Cost':[],'rank':[],'CD':[]}
pop=np.tile(empty_ind,(nP,1))
for i in range(nP):
    pop[i,0]['X']=np.random.uniform(Xmin,Xmax,[1,n])
    def MOP5(a):
        #n=np.size(x)
        x=a[0,0]
        y=a[0,1]
        
        f1=0.5*(x**2+y**2)+np.sin(x**2+y**2)
        f2=(3*x-2*y+4)**2/8 + (x-y+1)**2/27 +15
        f3=1/(x**2+y**2+1)- 1.1*np.exp(-x**2-y**2)
        aa=[f1,f2,f3]
        z=np.reshape(aa,(3,1))
        return z

    pop[i,0]['Cost']=MOP5(pop[i,0]['X'])
print(pop)
```

and this is my result :

```
[{'X': array([[ 11.65978708, -17.46716958]]), 'Cost': array([[2.21468705e+02],
       [7.31520444e+02],
       [2.26217399e-03]]), 'rank': [], 'CD': []}]
 [{'X': array([[ 11.65978708, -17.46716958]]), 'Cost': array([[2.21468705e+02],
       [7.31520444e+02],
       [2.26217399e-03]]), 'rank': [], 'CD': []}]
```

please let me know, why the results are the same?

Comment: I suspect that `np.tile` actually tiles the same dict object. So when you assign something to `pop[i,0]['X']`, it actually modifies all the dicts at the same time (because the dicts are the same).

Comment: You're right @j1-lee - `id(pop[2,0])`, `id(pop[12,0])`, `id(pop[49,0])`, etc. all return the same number.

Comment: The exact function (`tile` vs `list.__mul__`) is different, but the diagnosis and solution are exactly the same. Also, don't bother with numpy arrays when storing python objects. It gives you almost no advantage to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `np.tile` actually tiles the same dict object (in this case `empty_ind`). So when you assign something to `pop[i, 0]['X']`, you modify the all the dicts at the same time (because those dict are indeed the same object).

Try something like:

```py
pop = [{'X':[],'Cost':[],'rank':[],'CD':[]} for _ in range(nP)] # make a new object {...} at each for iteration

for i in range(nP):
    pop[i]['X']=np.random.uniform(Xmin,Xmax,[1,n])
    def MOP5(a):
        #n=np.size(x)
        x=a[0,0]
        y=a[0,1]
        
        f1=0.5*(x**2+y**2)+np.sin(x**2+y**2)
        f2=(3*x-2*y+4)**2/8 + (x-y+1)**2/27 +15
        f3=1/(x**2+y**2+1)- 1.1*np.exp(-x**2-y**2)
        aa=[f1,f2,f3]
        z=np.reshape(aa,(3,1))
        return z

    pop[i]['Cost']=MOP5(pop[i]['X'])
print(pop)
```

Here I chose to use `list` instead of `np.array` for `pop`; having a numpy array of dicts does not make much sense to me anyways.

Comment: Specifically, numpy arrays store a reference to a python object, so `np.tile(empty_ind,(nP,1))` works exactly the same as if you had a list and did `nP * [empty_ind]`.